# BIRT Margin Issue in Web Viewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt

I am a newbie in BIRT 4.3.2.

In my report I have one table with 3 detail rows. Each detail row has one separate table in it.Page break conditions for outer table and inner table is set to auto (for after, before, inside).

The problem I am facing is, the page is reducing in size when I view it in web viewer (and then export it to PDF).

I have checked the master page width. I am using US letter type which has width 215.9 mm. I checked the sum of margin width and table width, its 215.76 which is lesser than the page width still the page is getting reduced. My master page has only a footer with width 184mm.

I tried setting a page width at beforefactory but that did not worked either.

I used page interval but then my outer table breaks in between which is not acceptable.

Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: It is difficult to figure what is the problem with so few informations.There are probably paddings applied on report elements or something like that. You should try to post a simple .rptdesign based on "classicmodels" BIRT database sample and showing this issue.

Comment: "The Page is reducing in size" This means it is smaller than you expect  or it is smaller than that of in pdf?